# How to dynamically configure Httpsecurity in the Resource server using Spring security OAuth2 in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am new to Spring OAuth 2. I would like to know how configure `Httpsecurity` in Resource server dynamically using Spring OAuth 2.0. Since I have list of `antMatchers` and `scopes` that are stored in the database (may be in future `antMatchers` and `scopes` can be added).

For single `antMatchers` and `scope` I have tried it like below and it worked as expected:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/adminservice/")
        .access("#oauth2.hasScope('Products')");
}
```

How should I configure it if there are a list of `antMatchers` and `scopes` that are stored in the database such as:

```
**antMatchers**     **scopes**
/adminservice/      products
/xxxx/              yyyy
/yyyy/              xxxx
/jkjlk/             uyuuy
/klklk/             hjkskjk
```

Here while spring booting itself want to configure the `antMatchers` with respective `scope` from the database dynamically in the resource server.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your database access mechanism just autowire your jdbcTemplate, entityService and do:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    List<Matcher> matchers=matchersService.getAll();
    for(Matcher m : matchers) {
      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(m.getMapping())
        .access("#oauth2.hasScope('"+m.getScope()+"')");
    }
}
```

Now that will solve the configuration during startup. If you want to be able to dynamically change this during runtime I would simply suggest restarting the server if it's an option.

Comment: Is Matcher an entity from your DB?